# Using subfigures to add two pictures next to each other

Tags: graphics

Im am struggling to add two pictures next to each other. They don't align with the a) and b) below and tend to overlap whatever else I have on the page.

The images align at very, very, very small sizes, but as I increase the size they move out of the page (to the right). I increase the size by increasing the value in (width=.002\textwidth) to for example (width=.005\textwidth)

[image: As I increase the (width=.002\textwidth) the images leave the page to the right]

My code:

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}                
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}                
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot}          
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true}       
\usepackage{booktabs}                           
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.002\textwidth]{Fig/Results/19x.png}
  \caption{1a}
  \label{fig:sfig1}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.002\textwidth]{Fig/Results/8x.png}
  \caption{1b}
  \label{fig:sfig2}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{plots of....}
\label{fig:figkijbn}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide small but complete document, beginning with`\documentclass` and ending with `\ęnd{document}` which will show your proble. from your code snippet should after replacing `width=.002\textwidth` with `width=\linewidth` works fine.

Comment: Hi Zarko
I added the beginning of the code, there is a lot of different packages used, and honestly I dont know if I need half of it.

Replacing width=.002\textwidth to width=\linewidth gives an error "Dimentions too large"

Answer (score 2):

- i can't say which packages you really need, it depends from document content.
- not needed packages in your preamble are `graphics` (loaded by `graphicx`) and `amsmath` (loaded by `mathtools`)
- since i don't have your pictures, instead them i use `demo` option for the package `graphicx`. with them your code work as expected
- width of images is sensible determined by width of `subfigure` environments (see mwe below)

mwe (minimal working example):

```
\documentclass[english, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% \usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot,
         separate-uncertainty = true}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage[biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig/Results/19x.png}
    \caption{1a}
    \label{fig:sfig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig/Results/8x.png}
    \caption{1b}
    \label{fig:sfig2}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{plots of....}
\label{fig:figkijbn}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

if this document not work with your original images, than you have some malfunction in them.

Comment: The demo option gives the same result as you illustrate above. So there is something wrong with my pictures? 
Here is a link to the picture I am trying to use.

https://i.imgur.com/tv8qNyO.png

Comment: I sent the picture to a friend on facebook, and suddenly, the facebook-compressed-version of the image worked. This is so bizarre

Comment: @EirikAndreNordbø, how big is your picture (in pixels)? i very rare use `png` format, so i haven't experiences with it and limitation with its size, with 600 dpi resolution it should work (well compilation will slow down).

Answer (score 0):

The png image was the problem. I editet the image in Paint.Net and the result was not possible to use in Latex. Resizing it to a smaller resolution, gave no result. Changing the image to jpeg did not work either.

After sending it to a friend via facebook, it worked. The facebook compressed version worked, but not the original. Something was wrong with the data of the image which made it visually flawless in an image viewer, but problematic in LaTeX.

I am not sure what was wrong with the picture. I found an other question where someone, with a similar problem as me, said the resolution was given in 3500000/10000 instead of 350/1, which he meant was the source of the problem. He found this by using ImageMagick's -verbose function (I dont know this program)